# Friend function > validity range

Tags: c++, linux, friend-function

I am wondering what the validity range is for a `friend` function.
In my case I want to grant access to private members. But what if in another program there is also a function `FF()`?

h-file:

```
#ifndef LIB_FRIEND_H
#define LIB_FRIEND_H

class Lib_Friend{
friend int FF(Lib_Friend *vFF);
private:
    int TestFF();
    int Test;
public:
    Lib_Friend();
};

#endif // LIB_FRIEND_H
```

c-file:

```
#include "lib_friend.h"

int FF(Lib_Friend *vFF){
    vFF->Test = 1;
    return vFF->Test;
}

Lib_Friend::Lib_Friend(){
}

int Lib_Friend::TestFF(){
    return FF(this);
}
```

Prog:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "lib_friend.h"

    int FF(Lib_Friend *vFF){
        vFF->Test = 1;
        std::cout << "TEST A = " << vFF->Test << "\0";
// This works...
        return vFF->Test;
    }

    int main(){
    Lib_Friend mLib_Friend;
        std::cout << "TEST B = " << mLib_Friend.Test << "\0";
// This causes error...
        FF(&mLib_Friend);
        return 0;
    }
```

The question is:

Does a `friend` function grant access only by its name, or are there other parameters too? I hope, I have properly shown, what I mean and you can understand it.

(BTW: I've tried that above and it works. I really have access on a private member only because I have in another programm a function named FF (in this example).)

The other question naturally is: Is this avoidable for a `friend` function?

Comment: BTW: This will certainly work with friend class, too... (untested yet)

Comment: Friend declarations are handled by the compiler, there's nothing in the generated code about friend declarations. Therefore it has to be purely symbolic leading to both your library function and your program function being friends with the class ***iff*** they both have the exact same name ***and*** signature as the `friend` declaration.

Comment: add Angew: Maybe the code above is not "safe". But I tried it _save_ in a Test-Project. And there it works..., I have access on a private member of a class of a lib through a function in a programm which uses the lib, which has  the friend function (FF in this case).

Comment: Updated my first post with working code... The question still exist: Is there chance to avoid this behavior of a friend function?

Answer (score 2):

If a program defines its own version of `FF` different from the one in your library, it's violating the One Definition Rule because it has two different definitions for the function `int FF(class_A*)`. Therefore, it is not a well-formed C++ program.

Normally, this should result in a linker error. Even if it does not, the program will not have any defined behaviour, so for all intents and purposes, it is buggy. And buggy programs can do anything.

Comment: If a symbol is already defined, it will not be loaded from the library by the linker. It's not uncommon to "override" library functions that way.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Doesn't that require the symbol in the library to be weak?

Comment: No, probably because is a symbol is defined the linker simply does not look for it again, I would guess.